# Pattern for reading a sequential input file

Tags: cobol

I've been seeing a lot of examples for reading a sequential file in COBOL that looks something like this:

```
FD File-Record
01  Input-Record.
    88  End-Of-File       VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
    05  ...

...

    READ File-Record
        AT END SET End-Of-File TO TRUE
    END-READ

    PERFORM UNTIL End-Of-File
        PERFORM Process-Record
        READ File-Record
            AT END SET End-Of-File TO TRUE
        END-READ
    END-PERFORM
```

One question is, would it be just as well to process it as follows?

```
    PERFORM UNTIL End-Of-File
        READ File-Record
            AT END SET End-Of-File TO TRUE
            NOT AT END PERFORM Process-Record
        END-READ
    END-PERFORM
```

I've not generally seen the second pattern, but it seems more concise and less redundant to me. Is there a problem with it versus the first? I'm not referring to variations on the theme above (they can be grouped differently depending upon how you define what you `PERFORM` on) but I'm referring to the concept of the *first record pre-read* pattern, which seems to be favored in various examples I've seen.

Comment: Bill Woodger answered the question. The reason for the prevalence of the priming read and the PERFORM outside the READ is that it was the way it was done long before the NOT AT END was added to the READ syntax.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks, that's interesting to know (+1). Do you happen to know when `NOT AT END` was introduced?

Comment: The Cobol 85 standard X3.23-1985 is not available on the Internet.  It's available for purchase.  My recollection is the NOT AT END clause was added to the Cobol READ statement in the 1985 standard.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I can find `NOT AT END` in an old IBM COBOL manual to the '68 standard. No FILE STATUS. I'll have to try to check, but I think FILE STATUS is COBOL '74.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Now located AT END in a 1960 report to CODASYL on COBOL.

Comment: @Bill Woodger: Was the NOT AT END in the 68 manual an IBM extension?  As far as I recall, AT END was always a clause of the READ statement.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Sorry, I completely missed the fact that you wrote "NOT". I wondered why you had said that, but I should have been wondering why I read that. I pasted from your comment and put the backticks on. The NOT (AT END/INVALID KEY) would be '85, along with the END- constructs. I can't pin FILE STATUS to '74. Prior to '85 I used (written for us) Assembler IO routines, which had a flag, so FILE STATUS killed two birds with one stone (errors and result), exactly as the IO routines had done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is called a "Priming Read". Using this means there is always a record available going into the processing loop.

The second is called... well, not sure that's got a name. Within the processing loop the availability of a record has to be tested for.

A couple of things. Using the `AT END/NOT AT END/END-READ` is in itself somewhat unwieldy (opinion). There is a cleaner way (two reasons for it being cleaner).

On the SELECT statement for your file (you should do this for all files) define a `FILE STATUS` field, individual per file.

After every file-access, test the file-status field for that file, and ensure the access gave an expected result.

Using this method, the file-status field will be automatically set to `10` when end-of-file is reached. So you move the 88 to the file-status field, and change the `VALUE` to 10.

```
01  INPUT-FILE-STATUS                PIC XX.
    88  INPUT-FILE-OK                VALUE ZERO "10".
    88  INPUT-FILE-EOF               VALUE "10".

PERFORM                       PRIMING-READ
PERFORM UNTIL End-Of-File
    PERFORM                   Process-Record
    PERFORM                   READ-A-RECORD05 is optional file not present, 23 is record not found.
END-PERFORM

...
PRIMING-READ.
    PERFORM                   READ-A-RECORD
    IF INPUT-FILE-EOF
        [cancel with end-of-file on first read message]
    END-IF
    .

READ-A-RECORD.
    READ File-Record
    IF NOT INPUT-FILE-OK
        [code here to check file-status field and crash if bad]
    END-IF
    .
```

I strongly favour the priming-read. An "empty" file may indicate a problem. Now you can test (after the priming read) without having to clutter your main logic. You don't have to "get out of the loop" at end-of-file, because the loop is only ever entered with a current record.

Traditionally files would contain "headers" (and "trailers"). The header would contain a date, logical-file-name, etc. The header would be read and verified to know that the correct file was being processed. Then you need to check that there are not *two* headers (because if you don't, one day there will be). Whilst you've done that, you already have the first data record.

You don't want to do all that in amongst some "business" logic or to clutter the flow of the logic.

On the 88 on the input-record, be aware that this is non-transportable across other COBOLs. On an IBM Mainframe, for instance, unless your input is variable-length records and you use APPLY WRITE ONLY (explicitly, or implicitly by the horrible compiler option AWO) then accessing data under an FD before a file is open, after it is closed, or after end-of-file will lead to a crash (ABEND).

Comment: Thanks Bill.  And you answered my unasked question about the `88` EOF status. I tossed in that mechanism I had read about in a couple of places as a "clever" way to handle the option. I personally would favor portability over clever in this case. So using the file status obviates the need to use the `EOF` flag altogether?

Comment: No need to use AT END/NOT AT END/END-READ at all. Same with INVALID KEY/NOT INVALID KEY. No END-WRITEs either. I don't think I've ever coded them except in examples. 88s on the FILE STATUS field, 00 is AOK, 10 ie EOF. There are other values, they are Standard, although compiler implementors have been known to Extend them.

Comment: And yes, the FILE STATUS field *becomes* the end-of-file flag (and the invalid keyed read/keyed write etc). Automatically set by the IO code, so you know that when it is wrong it is wrong (unless you typo the 88 VALUEs).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you only call `PERFORM Process-Record` once, so in this respect there is no improvement in the second pattern.

Then you are working in Cobol but are worrying about the finesses of patterns. I would rather worry about working in Cobol versus higher/newer languages. Some 25 years ago I used `Protos` as a layer to hide raw Cobol . . .

Comment: Are you then implying there's nothing functionally wrong with the second method versus the first? (Discussions about opinions regarding COBOL's relevance, etc, are not part of my question.)

Comment: The `PERFORM Process-Record` only appears once in the source, but it is executed for each successful read. Not sure what you mean. Perhaps you hid your COBOL too much.

Comment: If the `Perform` on the record actually exists of several lines of code, then it would be nice not to have that code duplicated. Just to duplicate the `read` command does not clutter your code that much.

Comment: I think it is an example asking about the two different styles: read once before the loop and at the end of the loop VS only read once in the loop and avoid data-processing if end-of-file is found. Both styles can be implemented in many ways, the question is why is one style predominant when the other style seems more succinct.