# How to read two records and compare them with a primary key in sequential file system?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

This is the record format for my input file:

```
ID NAME Purchaseamount month
1  xxx  10000           feb
1  xxx  10000            mar
1  xxx  10000           apr
2  yyy  100              jan
2  yyy  2054             mar
```

How can I add the purchase amount for every person? I will give you the pseudo-code of my work.

```
Read inputfile,
move to working storage variables,
end read,
perform until eof,
read input file,
if inputid = ws-input id,
add purchase amount,
else write to output file
```

Comment: Have you tried running it ???. Th second read should be at the end

Comment: I tried running it. Only the last record in my input gets readed and written in output. No operations were performed. @brucemartin

Comment: how about showing us your code

Comment: You have a check for `if inputid = ws-input id`, where do you set the prior `id` that you're comparing to? It's not visible in your pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

Bruce provides a good solution, but there is often more than one way to do things.  Here is an alternate solution (in pseudocode) that is inspired by Michael A. Jackson's "Principles of Program Design" (I recommend it if you have not read it).

```
OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE
READ INPUT-FILE 
PERFORM PROCESS-PERSON UNTIL INPUT-FILE-EOF
CLOSE INPUT-FILE
STOP RUN
.

PROCESS-PERSON.
    MOVE INPUT-ID TO LAST-INPUT-ID
    MOVE ZERO TO PURCHASE-TOTAL
    PERFORM PROCESS-RECORD UNTIL INPUT-FILE-EOF OR
        (INPUT-ID NOT = LAST-INPUT-ID)
    WRITE PERSON-TOTAL
    .

PROCESS-RECORD.
    ADD PURCHASE-AMOUNT TO PURCHASE-TOTAL
    READ INPUT-FILE
    .
```

Comment: For @lurker this shows the advantage of clobbering the key to "as high as can be" from the "pattern" question http://stackoverflow.com/q/28700006/1927206 . If they key has a "break" at end-of-file, you don't have two tests for end-of-file, you have one for "break" and one for "end-of-file", simplifying. `READ ... INTO ...` is one way to do that, so key is in `WORKING-STORAGE` but that will move all the data each time. Keeping just the key in WORKING-STORAGE allows the clobbering to be transportable across COBOLs.

Comment: If you have a file-trailer, you naturally get the "break" on the last data, change the first loop to end on identifying the file-trailer, and then process the file-trailer, ensuring there are no records after it (so, READ, and if not end-of-file, there is a problem).

Comment: It is a neat way to represent any structure in the file: process data; process agent; process customers of agent. I call this "sideways" processing: instead of processing all at one "level" (so a read-loop with EVALUATE for instance), you process each subordinate structure "to the right" of its immediate higher level. Presto: the structure of the program reflects the structure of the file.

Answer (score 1):

for pseudo code Try:

```
 move 0            to purchaseTotal
 Read InputFile
 move inputId      to lastInputId
 Perform until eof
     if inputId = lastInputId
        add purshaseAmount     to purchaseTotal
     else
        write personTotal
        move 0                 to purchaseTotal 
        move inputId      to lastInputId
     end-if  
     Read InputFile
end-Perform
write personTotal
```

do you have any code and the result ???

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the best program is one you don't have to write.

This really is a problem that begs for a utility tool solution.  Syncsort will do match and sums type things, so will other tools like FileAid and FileManager.  You could probably knock that out with two or three lines of config information.