# COBOL logic for de-normalized file to Normalized table

Tags: logic, cobol

How to load de-normalized file to Normalized table. I'm new to cobol, any suggestion on the below requirement. Thanks.

Inbound file: FileA.DAT

```
ABC01
ABC2014/01/01
FDE987
FDE2012/01/06
DEE6759
DEE2014/12/12
QQQ444
QQQ2004/10/12
RRR678
RRR2001/09/01
```

Table : TypeDB

```
TY_CD    Varchar(03)
SEQ_NUM  CHAR(10)
END_DT   DATE
```

I have to write a COBOL program to load the table : TypeDB
Output of the result should be,

```
TY_CD   SEQ_NUM END_DT
ABC     01      2014/01/01
FDE     987     2012/01/06
DEE     6759    2014/12/12
QQQ     444     2004/10/12
RRR     678     2001/09/01
```

Below is the pseudo-codeish

```
Perform Until F1 IS EOF 
    Read F1 
    MOVE F1-REC to WH1-REC 
    Read F1 
    MOVE F1-REC to WH2-REC 
    IF WH1-TY-CD = WH2-TY-CD 
        move WH1-TY-CD to TY-CD 
        move WH1-CD to SEQ_NUM 
        move WH2-DT to END-DT 
    END-IF 
END-PERFORM
```

This is not working.. any thing better? instead read 2 inside the perform?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're new to COBOL but I suppose this is an assignment and you've been given some instruction in areas that are needed to solve this problem.

Comment: I have tried by confused lot and stopped continue... Below is the pseudo-codeish

Comment: I have tried by confused lot and stopped continue... Below is the pseudo-codeish   Perform Until F1 IS EOF

Read F1
 MOVE F1-REC to WH1-REC
Read F1
 MOVE F1-REC to WH2-REC

IF WH1-TY-CD = WH2-TY-CD
 move WH1-TY-CD to TY-CD 
 move WH1-CD to SEQ_NUM
 move WH2-DT to END-DT
END-IF

END-PERFORM
This is not working.. any thing better? instead read 2 inside the perform?

Comment: Please do not add code or pseudo-code into comments. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28814908/edit) your question and add it there, properly formatted.

Comment: Can you check the edit? In what way is it not working? What output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go with reading in pairs, like you have. It is clearer, to me, than having "flags" to say what is going on.

I suspect you've overwritten your first record with the second without realising it.

A simple way around that, for a beginner, is to use `READ ... INTO ...` to get your two different layouts. As you become more experienced, you'll perhaps save the data you need from the first record, and just use the second record from the FD area.

Here's some pseudo-code. It is the same as yours, but by using a "Priming Read". This time the Priming Read is reading two records. No problem.

By testing the FILE STATUS field as indicated, the paired structure of the file is verified. Checking the key ensures that the pairs are always for the same "key" as well. All built-in and hidden away from your actual logic (which in this case is not much anyway).

```
PrimingRead
FileLoop Until EOF
    ProcessPair
    ReadData
EndFileLoop

ProcessPair
   Do the processing from Layout1 and Layout2

PrimingRead
    ReadData
    Crash with non-zero file-status

ReadData
    ReadRec1
    ReadRec2
    If Rec2-key not equal to Rec1-key, crash

ReadRec1
    Read Into Layout1
    Crash with non-zero file-status

ReadRec2
    Read Into Layout2
    Crash with file-status other than zero or 10
```

While we are at it, we can apply this solution from Valdis Grinbergs as well (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28744236/1927206).

```
PrimingRead
FileLoop Until EOF
    ProcessPair
    ReadPairStructure
EndFileLoop

ProcessPair
   Do the processing from Layout1 and Layout2

PrimingRead
    ReadPairStructure
    Crash with non-zero file-status

ReadPairStructure
    ReadRec1
    ReadSecondOfPair

ReadSecondOfPair
    ReadRec2
    If Rec2-key not equal to Rec1-key, crash

ReadRec1
    Read Into Layout1
    Crash with non-zero file-status

ReadRec2
    Read Into Layout2
    Crash with file-status other than zero or 10
```

Because the structure of the file is very simple either can do. With fixed-number-groups of records, I'd go for the read-a-group-at-a-time. With a more complex structure, the second, "sideways".

Either method clearly reflects the structure of the file, and when you do that in your program, you aid the understanding of the program for human readers (which may be you some time in the future).

Comment: Thanks Bill. Looks promising. let me convert into real code and see.

Comment: @Ammu It is very close to what you have, just with a rearrangement. Thinking again, your existing pseudo-code has a problem when end-of-file is encountered, as you attempt a second read and process the data. The Priming Read will sort all that out.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Much appreciate your explanation.